# MySQL: How to properly extract blob data from mysqlbinlog output

Tags: mysql, data-recovery, mysqlbinlog

I am trying to restore a few erroneous updates to a customer MySQL 5.7 database. Binlogs are enabled (`binlog_format=MIXED`). I am trying to write a script that will go through the binlogs and restore the rows to their previous values.
I am using `mysqbinlog` like this:

`mysqlbinlog -vv --base64-output=decode-rows mysql-bin-000001`.

The only problem is that the values are BLOB fields containing binary data, and unfortunately I can't find a way to handle them using the `mysqlbinlog` utility:

```
#220131  7:41:04 server id 227  end_log_pos 216096 CRC32 0xc1899f91     Update_rows: table id 109 flags: STMT_END_F
### UPDATE `db`.`contents`
### WHERE
###   @1=31508332458 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @2='���N�0\x10�...' /* MEDIUMBLOB/MEDIUMTEXT meta=3 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
### SET
###   @1=31508332458 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @2='\u' /* MEDIUMBLOB/MEDIUMTEXT meta=3 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
```

Ideally, I want to be able to represent the second field `@2` using hex, so I can export the data to csv (`@1,HEX(@2)`), but that doesn't seem to be possible. Is there any way to extract blobs without treating them as strings, so I can get the data back? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but I'd grab the `mysqlbinlog` from MariaDB and use [flashback](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/flashback/) to generate the SQL.

In theory, being just DML, this should be MySQL compatible or only require small modification to achieve the final result.

Comment: Never heard of the `flashback` switch before. This did it! I was able to revert a copy of the database to a state before the erroneous updates. The rest is easy. Case closed. Thank you!